# Segmentation fault on file IO

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, server

So my task is to implement a load function for a **very** simple server. And i cant really figure out where my segmentation fault is. I've tried to use GDB but since i use telnet with which i send http headers as input i've had a hard time with getting any results from it.

the function:

```
 //Loads a file into memory dynamically allocated on heap.
 //Stores address thereof in *content and length thereof in *length.

bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length)
{
    //checks so file is open
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    } 

    char* buffert = malloc(BYTES * sizeof(char));

    while(true)
    {

        // read into buffert
        fread(buffert, BYTES, sizeof(char), file);

        //store the pointer of this buffert in content
        *content = buffert;

        //update length
        length += 1;

        // checks for eof
        if(feof(file) != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

   free(buffert);

   return true;
}
```

"...`BYTE`, which we’ve indeed defined as an 8-bit char."

Thx!!

Comment: Ahem... 'free(buffert);'

Comment: @MartinJames Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

```
  *content = buffert;
```

vs.

```
   free(buffert);
```

`BYTE** content` points to memory which was de-allocated. you probably want to keep this data alive as long as `buffert` is alive, and deallocate it then.

plus, you probably meant to write `length += BYTES` , since you are already reading the whole file as once. (also, the `while(true)` is un-needed)

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I'm following you. I free my buffert after i've read the entire file. So by then I would have the contents of buffert already stored in a pointer (is it there the error is?) and no more use of it right?

Comment: the only thing you stored into the pointer is the mamoery address of the buffer. a single pointer can hold itself the content of a file. it can point to a buffer which holds it.